# Appending content with different user

Tags: perl, shell, unix

My script is creating a `gt.txt` file with abc user and writing some content into it. I have another script which is appending the content to the same file `gt.txt` but since it is being run as a different user, it is throwing an error.

What shall I do? Any possible solutions? Both are shell scripts but are run as different users.

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: Its giving the error as cannot create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the error you are getting is 'permission denied'.

One option is to create a group, which both users can belong to, and assign group permissions to the file which allow group members to write to the file. Like this:

```
groupadd gtgroup
usermod -a -G gtgroup abcuser
usermod -a -G gtgroup defuser
chgrp gtgroup gt.txt
chmod g+rw gt.txt
```

You will need to issue most of those commands as root or via sudo. Also, groupadd and usermod commands may vary from one unix-like system to another.

If the file is being created from within the perl script, then you might have to perform the chgrp and chmod within the perl script. Use Perl [chown](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chown.html) and [chmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chmod.html) for that.

Comment: are there any parameters with which can change the group forcefully?

Comment: Sorry Angel I do not understand your question.  If run as root chgrp will change the group "forcefully"